# AI model doesn't store the best set of neurons correctly

Tags: python, list, for-loop, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Behold the convoluted mess of code that was created in the process of trying to make an AI from scratch:

```
neurons = averageImage
bestNeurons = averageImage

for x in range(numberOfGenerations):
    neurons = bestNeurons
        for y in range(numberOfNeurons):  # Get the score of the neurons applied to the images
        weights[y] = random.uniform(0.999, 1.001)
        neurons[y] = weights[y] * neurons[y]
        if float(averageImage[y]) == 0.0 == float(neurons[y]):
            dataGapArray[y] = 0.0
        elif float(averageImage[y]) >= float(neurons[y]):
            dataGapArray[y] = (float(neurons[y]) / float(averageImage[y]))
        elif float(averageImage[y]) >= float(neurons[y]):
            dataGapArray[y] = (float(neurons[y]) / float(averageImage[y]))
    totalImageScore = (sum(dataGapArray) / numberOfNeurons)
    for z in range(numberOfNeurons):  # Get the score of the neurons applied to the placebos
        if float(averagePlacebo[z]) == 0.0 == float(neurons[z]):
            dataGapArray[z] = 0.0
        elif float(averagePlacebo[z]) >= float(neurons[z]):
            dataGapArray[z] = (float(neurons[z]) / float(averagePlacebo[z]))
        elif float(averagePlacebo[z]) >= float(neurons[z]):
            dataGapArray[z] = (float(neurons[z]) / float(averagePlacebo[z]))
    totalPlaceboScore = (sum(dataGapArray) / numberOfNeurons)
    currentGenerationScore = (totalImageScore - totalPlaceboScore)
    if currentGenerationScore > bestScore:
        print("New best score!: ", currentGenerationScore)
        bestNeurons = neurons
        bestScore = currentGenerationScore
        print("Best set of neurons:", bestNeurons)
        bestImageScore = totalImageScore
        bestPlaceboScore = totalPlaceboScore

print("Best image score:", bestImageScore)
print("Best placebo score:", bestPlaceboScore)
print("Final best set of neurons:", bestNeurons)
```

The AI gets the average of all the histograms of the images and placebos as the lists averageImage and averagePlacebo, and initiates a neuron from each RGB value of the averageImage list (768 neurons in total). Then, it sets a random coefficient (weight) to each neuron. Then, it calculates how much the current model differs from the two averages, and tries to maximize this difference, thus:

```
currentGenerationScore = (totalImageScore - totalPlaceboScore)
```

If the current set of neurons obtains a higher score than the current best score, it stores the current list neurons as bestNeurons, the new high score, with its best image score and best placebo score.

However, when I print() the set of best neurons afterwards, it doesn't print the same list as when I print it immediatly after setting a new high score.

In the console it displays something like this:

```
New best score!:  0.08557032861714253 #The last high score to appear in the console
Best set of neurons: [90.80510337491788, 21.407473725714194, 24.565764120524587...
Best image score: 1.0
Best placebo score: 0.9150773121149368
Final best set of neurons: [88.07822102513295, 18.731741148965224, 24.179414725919838...
```

As you can see, my crappy block of code doesn't store the best set of neurons, even if it calculates the score right (because I can see it increasing in a constant, regular way). I should be seeing the same identical list of bestNeurons, as it is the last one to be found.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve your problem, but have you seen the tutorial by sentdex on how to create a neural network from scratch. It might give you some insights on what could your errors be. https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcjD5BAw2DxE6OF2tius3V3

Comment: I think this can be because your neurons list is the same list throughout. When you save it for the best score, you don't save a copy of it, so changes to that list in the next iterations also change the saved list. Try using `copy.deepcopy`